# How to disable WinAPI ListView selection highlighting

Tags: c++, listview, winapi

I have a ListView in pure WinAPI. When I click on an item, it puts it in a blue box and sends a click message to the parent window per default styles. However, I am looking for a way to disable this default functionality. Is there a way to simply turn off the highlighting while still having the NM_CLICK message be sent.

Comment: Owner-draw the ListView, then you can make it look anyway you want

Comment: You need to customize drawing, you can refer to:[How to change highlight color in list control in mfc](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4c800136-5b61-41ad-9855-bdfd1f4c9b89/how-to-change-highlight-color-in-list-control-in-mfc?forum=vcgeneral) and [Using Custom Draw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/using-custom-draw)